# Passportjs documentation - meaning of function

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

On this [Passportjs.org](http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/) page, the documentation gives an example of using a LocalStrategy, and within the LocalStrategy, it calls a function:

```
User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
  if (err) { return done(err); }
  if (!user) {
    return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
  }
  if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
    return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
  }
  return done(null, user);
});
```

Now, I'm seeing this "`User`" object crop up in multiple places, such as in the documentation for the [passport-windowsauth](https://github.com/auth0/passport-windowsauth) strategy, where the following function is used in an example:

```
User.findOrCreate()
```

So now I'm wondering if I'm crazy.

Is this 'User' object and its functions some existing framework or set of functions, or are these just examples of your own home-grown function for finding a user?

Comment: You could probably quoute yourself. "The documentation gives an example of using a LocalStrategy" - Examples are always examples. You are free to interpret and implement the code as you see fit.

Comment: Schledgehammur, an 'example' of some node.js code could include the function `res.writeHead()`, which is a built in function to a node response object. The fact that it is included in an example doesn't answer the question as to whether it is a built in function or not.

Comment: `User` is a part of the frame work but functions `findOne` and `findOrCreate` are not. They are just examples of how one can use the `User`.

Comment: `User` isn't part of Passport. The example code uses a [Mongoose-like](http://mongoosejs.com/) model called `User` as an example how to integrate Passport with, for instance, a database framework. I agree that the examples should point that out, so people don't expect the example code to Just Work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User is a object which contains information about users and findOne or findById or findByusername are just prototype functions associated with this object.

They have assumed a User schema ([Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) user schema) for all the examples they have given. it comes with all the mentioned prototype functions attached with it

From their working example (without Mongoose schema) :
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/tree/master/examples/express3

Adding code in case of link expiration:

```
var users = [
    { id: 1, username: 'bob', password: 'secret', email: 'bob@example.com' }
  , { id: 2, username: 'joe', password: 'birthday', email: 'joe@example.com' }
];

    function findById(id, fn) {
      var idx = id - 1;
      if (users[idx]) {
        fn(null, users[idx]);
      } else {
        fn(new Error('User ' + id + ' does not exist'));
      }
    }

    function findByUsername(username, fn) {
      for (var i = 0, len = users.length; i < len; i++) {
        var user = users[i];
        if (user.username === username) {
          return fn(null, user);
        }
      }
      return fn(null, null);
    }
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
      function(username, password, done) {
        process.nextTick(function () {
          findByUsername(username, function(err, user) {
            if (err) { return done(err); }
            if (!user) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown user ' + username }); }
            if (user.password != password) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' }); }
            return done(null, user);
          })
        });
      }
    ));
```

Reference:
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/tree/master/examples/express3

Comment: Great! This makes a lot more sense. So essentially, the searching and validation is being done right in the Strategy's verify function, and the localstrategy itself primarily just pulls the user data correctly out of the request body. This is what I couldn't figure out with this misunderstood.

Comment: yup you can look in to strategy file of passport-local,passport-http (basic,digest) to see how request is handled to get the authentication info